# how to do HTTP POST request in GWT

Tags: java, http, gwt, post

I have a problem.. I use "GWT"; I have a string in client side.
I would send this string to server with a HTTP POST request but I have no idea how to do this.. 
What is the code that I have to write on client side and server side???
please help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look into the official documentation:

[Dev Server Commmunication](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html)

I am not a big fan of RPC, so I'd suggest to you [the HTTP calls here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests)

As the backend I'd create a REST architecture for handling the requests.